# How to implement a forward pass in a Keras RNN in real-time?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to run an RNN trained in Keras in an application that run's in real-time. The "time" in the recurrent network (it's an LSTM) here are actual moments in time when data is received.

I want to get the output of the RNN in an online fashion. For non-recurrent models, I just shaped my input into the shape `inputDatum=1,input_shape` and run `Model.predict` on it. I'm not sure this is the intended method of using forward pass in Keras for the application, but it worked for me.

But for recurrent modules, `Model.predict` expects as input the whole input, including temporal dimension. So it does not work...

Is there a way to do this in Keras or do I need to go down to Tensorflow and implement the operation there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `LSTM` layer to be stateful. The internal state of the LSTM will be kept until you call `model.reset_states()` manually.

For example, suppose we have trained a simple LSTM model.

```py
x = Input(shape=(None, 10))
h = LSTM(8)(x)
out = Dense(4)(h)
model = Model(x, out)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

X_train = np.random.rand(100, 5, 10)
y_train = np.random.rand(100, 4)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Then, the weights can be loaded onto another model with `stateful=True` for prediction (remember to set up `batch_shape` in the `Input` layer).

```py
x = Input(batch_shape=(1, None, 10))
h = LSTM(8, stateful=True)(x)
out = Dense(4)(h)
predict_model = Model(x, out)

# copy the weights from `model` to this model
predict_model.set_weights(model.get_weights())
```

For your use case, since `predict_model` is stateful, consecutive `predict` calls on length-1 sub-sequences will give the same result as predicting on the entire sequence. Just remember to call `reset_states()` before predicting a new sequence.

```py
X = np.random.rand(1, 3, 10)
print(model.predict(X))
# [[-0.09485822,  0.03324107,  0.243945  , -0.20729265]]

predict_model.reset_states()
for t in range(3):
    print(predict_model.predict(X[:, t:(t + 1), :]))
# [[-0.04117237 -0.06340873  0.10212967 -0.06400848]]
# [[-0.12808001  0.0039286   0.23223262 -0.23842749]]
# [[-0.09485822  0.03324107  0.243945   -0.20729265]]
```